# Magento site not showing products in admin?

Tags: import

Magento site not showing products in admin. BUT after an import they show in the categories in the back end of the website.

The products dont show in the front end. All I did was upload a newer csv with system > import/export > dataflow - profiles.

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure the products you uploaded have a stock status (in stock or out of stock) and a visibility set.

Comment: Yer thank you Marius, ive done that still nothing.

Comment: Thank you everyone, found the problem. Basically while importing you can choose an option to "replace complex data". We did that after deleting the database fields. It now works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Export CSV from "Dataflow Profile" and check and compare your csv field. because in your CSV have removed mandatory field thats why your products not display on admin panel. First check and resubmit your CSV from "dataflow Profile".

Answer (score 0):

Basically their may be an typo in the values of some column in the import sheet.May be you have invalid values to the products.like

- status column in the import should have values like Enabled or Disabled. Their may be some typo error to this columns (this is just an example)

why i gave this example is this is same happened to me.i had columns status and values as Enable and Disable instead of Enabled and Disabled

Note:- as you are saying that you are not able to see the products in the admin so i dnt think so you any other issues apart from typos

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Ive added a test product and exported it. There is one product in the backend of the website, but on the export it has more than the original import. (Imported 6600, exported 9000) 

You maybe right as the export was missing alot of info. Ill try to clean it and re upload it. Thanks guys.

Comment: Im running version 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Helo @idea21, how are you doing?

Look, I had a problem like your, and the best way I've found to Export/Import my Products (and Categories, and attributes, and images) was using eMagicOne Store Manager for Magento. It's a (paid) software, but you can signup and get 14 days on trial mode (with full access to all features).

If you want to try this software, you had to pay attention in some tricky steps to do it well.

1. Use Connection Wizard to Connectec to your OLD site;
2. After connected, Go to 'Tools' tab and click 'Get Data From Web';
3. After your data download finishes, you must click in right tab (which have the software icon) > Import / Export > Produtcts
4. Backup your DB
5. Follow the steps.

Once your Import was done, follow this steps:

1. Use Connection Wizard to Connectec to your NEW site;
2. After connected, Go to 'Tools' tab and click '**Get Data From Web**';
3. After your data download finishes, you must click in right tab (which have the software icon) > Import / Export > Produtcts
4. Backup your DB
5. Select Import & Follow the steps.
6. After the tools finishes the import go to 'Tools' tab and click '**Post Changes to Web**'

I hope it's solve your issue.

In time, please ignore my grammatical, I'm not a native English speaker (writer, in this case).

Best Regards!